# Does Tensorflow calculate these partial derivatives/gradient correctly?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm just starting learning Tensorflow and came across an example that doesn't make sense to me:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> a=tf.Variable(1.)
>>> b=2*a
>>> c=a+b
>>> g=tf.gradients(c, [a,b])
>>> sess=tf.Session()
2018-09-20 13:50:59.616341: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1195] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-09-20 13:50:59.616400: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1195] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:1) -> (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
>>> print sess.run(g)
[3.0, 1.0]
```

Since `c=3a`, I expected the first partial (partial c with respect to a) to be `3.0`. But, it is also true that `c=1.5b`, so I expected the second partial derivative to be `1.5`, not `1.0`.

On the other hand, if I do the following:

```
>>> b = tf.Variable(2.)
>>> a = 0.5*b
>>> c = a+b
>>> g = tf.gradients(c,[a,b])
```

I get this result:

```
>>> print sess.run(g)
[1.0, 1.5]
```

I have similar problems with this answer.

Additionally, I would think I'm looking for the same information about the same function at the same point with the same constraint in these two cases. I would expect the same answers.

Have I forgotten something truly embarrassing about partial derivatives or algebra? Or, am I fundamentally misunderstanding something about what I can expect from from Tensorflow gradients?

Is there something to do with the graph construction that ends up creating a situation where `b` depends on `a`, but `a` is independent of `b`? Or, is the true problem that gradients should only be taken with respect to variables that are strictly independent of each other?

Comment: First, the numbers in the code and the description do not match... you have `c = a + b` and `b = 2 * a`, so, with respect to `a`, you would have `c = 3 * a`, and in with respect to `b`, `c = constant + b`. `3` and `1` are the correct derivatives here.

Comment: @jdehesa - But, if `b=2a`, it is also true that `a=0.5b`, so doesn't `c=1.5b` just as reasonably as `c=3a`? Why isn't the `=` relationship being treated as fully symmetric here?

Comment: I see what you mean but it does not quite work like that. Imagine you have `g(x) = x + f(x)`, with `f(x) = 2 * x`. The derivative wrt `x` is 3, and the other derivative would be wrt `f(x)`, and would be 1. Here you take `f(x)` "as if" it were an independent variable, and the derivative being 1 means "if `f(x)` increases by `t` then `g(x)` will increase by `t * 1`". But `f(x)` increasing by `t` does not necessarily mean `x` increasing by `t / 2`, you could just say that now `f(x)` is `2 * x + t` (because you are treating `f(x)` as independent, so you could assign whatever value to it).